# CDF for non-homogeneous Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand the [inverse transform method](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4404-Sigman/4404-Notes-ITM.pdf) for simulating random processes and have managed to completely confuse myself.  Consider a Poisson process whose conditional intensity is

$$\lambda(t) = \alpha e^{-t}$$

starting at time $t=0$ for some parameter $\alpha>0$.

To apply the inverse transform method I need to start with the cdf (called $F$ in the notes that I have linked to) and then compute its inverse. What is the relevant cdf $F$ for this process?

My overall goal is to be able to simulate the arrival times from this process.

Comment: Is $t$ a continuous or discrete variable?

Comment: @EricTowers  It is a continuous variable.

Comment: @EricTowers Do you mean Poisson distribution?  "The Poisson process is a continuous-time process; the sum of a Bernoulli process can be thought of as its discrete-time counterpart"

Comment: The non-homogeneous Poisson process follows a Poisson distribution.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Non-homogeneous

Comment: @EricTowers Do you think I just need to integrate $\alpha e^{-t}$ over some suitable range?

Comment: See updated answer, below.

Comment: You chose to delete your previous question (with full answer) this one is a duplicate of, after the duplicate was signalled. Is this a try to circumvent the policy of the site?

Comment: Absolutely not! You can't delete an answer you have upvoted. In fact I think I have found a better way to simulate the process now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then why are you deleting your question and reposting it soon afterwards?

Comment: @Did You can vote to undelete (I just did); having a duplicate link point to nowhere isn't optimal.

Comment: @Thursday Right, done. (But I find this OP's behavior quite odd.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in the obvious place, the [non-homogeneous Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Non-homogeneous) uses the intensity function to construct a parameter for a Poisson process, which is a discrete probability distribution.  \begin{align*}
\lambda_{a,b} &= \int_a^b \lambda(t) ~\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_a^b \alpha \mathrm{e}^{-t} ~\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \alpha ( \cosh(a) - \sinh(a) - \cosh(b) + \sinh(b) )
\end{align*}
Inserting this value in the following doesn't result in any opportunities for simplification, so you should just compute it as some numerical value for a given $\alpha$, $a$, and $b$

The probability of $k$ events between times $a$ and $b$ is 
$$P[N(b)-N(a) = k] = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_{a,b}}(\lambda_{a,b})^k}{k!}$$

The cumulative distribution of up to $k$ events between times $a$ and $b$ is 
$$P[N(b)-N(a) \leq k] = \sum_{j=0}^k\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_{a,b}}(\lambda_{a,b})^j}{j!}$$

For your purpose you want to start with $j=0$ and then extend this sum by one term at a time until it exceeds your $U[0,1]$ variate and then return that value of $k$ as your Poisson variate.  (Note that exceeding the uniform variate can occur on the first, $k=0$, term and this is a valid value of a Poisson variate.)

Comment: Thank you for this. $t$ is continuous in a Poisson process I believe. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process .  I think in principle there should be a closed form for the inverse but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am surprised there isn't a closed form for this!

Comment: Do you mean start with $k=0$ and increase it by one at a time?

Comment: @Lembik:  There is, if you consider the incomplete gamma function to be "closed form".  But this closed form would be useless to you because you would be making your math library repeatedly evaluate this sum as you increment $k$.

Comment: @Lembik:  Yes...  Of course, the way to do it is to only evaluate the sum once, starting with $j=0$, then adding one more term at a time, virtually incrementing $k$, until you finally exceed your uniform deviate, then announcing you knew the right value to have been using for $k$ all along.

Comment: I think the integral $\lambda_{a,b}$ can be written more  simply by observing that $\int e^{-t} dt = -e^{-t} + c$ .

Comment: NB: A Poisson process is not a discrete probability distribution. A Poisson process is a stochastic process (∴ a distribution over an infinite indexed set of random variables, which if viewed in terms of a event-count perspective would be countably infinite and if in terms a time-set perspective would be uncountably infinite). The link between the two is that a Poisson process as a rate function defined over some space, and the number of events that occur in a subspace will be Poisson distributed with mean parameter equal to the rate function integrated over that subspace.